# best setup for live data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use elasticsearch for live data filtering. Right now I use a single machine which gets constantly pushed new data (every 3 seconds via _bulk). Even so I did set up a ttl the index gets quite big after a day or so and then elasticsearch hangs. My current mapping:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/live -d '{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase_keyword": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "no_keyword": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "_timestamp": {
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "datetime"
      },
      "_ttl":{
        "enabled":true,
        "default":"8h"
      },
      "properties": {
        "url": {
          "type": "string",
          "search_analyzer": "lowercase_keyword",
          "index_analyzer": "lowercase_keyword"
        },
        "q": {
          "type": "string",
          "search_analyzer": "no_keyword",
          "index_analyzer": "no_keyword"
        },
        "datetime" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I think a problem is purging the old documents but I could be wrong. Any ideas on how to optimize my setup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid elasticsearch hanging, you might want to increase amount of memory available to java process.

If all your documents have the same 8 hour life span, it might be more efficient to use rolling [aliases](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-aliases.html) instead of ttl. The basic idea is to create a new index periodically (every hour, for example) and use aliases to keep track of current indices. As time goes, you can update the list of indices in the alias that you search and simply delete indices that are more than 8 hour long. Deleting an index is much quicker than removing indices using ttl. A sample code that demonstrates how to create rolling aliases setup can be found [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1500).

I am not quite sure how much live data you are trying to keep, but if you are just testing incoming data against a set of queries, you might also consider using [Percolate API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/percolate.html) instead of indexing data.

Comment: Thanks. I still have to try it but the rolling aliases sound like the idea I was looking for.